# spring.config.location not working on spring boot 2.0.0 M6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm migrating one of my micro-services to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 and I got and error while using the `--spring.config.location=` option on the command line. The error is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'property' in value "${property}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:834) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
... 50 common frames omitted
```

If I don't use the custom property file everything works as intended or use the RELEASE versions. I'm starting the application with the following command:

`java -jar application.jar --spring.config.location=app.properties`

## Update

I notice that when using this option Spring completely replaces the default application.properties from the project, unlike previous Spring versions which just overwrites the properties in the argument file. Is this a bug?

## Update 2

Got a [response](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10971) from the team, apparently this is intended behavior. Trying to know now if there is a way to use the old versions behavior.

Comment: In the response Andy gave you a link that points to the way to use the old behavior: `spring.config.additional-location` instead of `spring.config.location`

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov yep, I tried that before but it didn't work. Must have typed something wrong or other thing 'cause when I tried again it worked

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated by the Spring team the correct way to use the old behavior from the `spring.config.location` is to use the new `spring.config.additional-location`

Comment: please, provide examples

Comment: For reference, here's the relevant item in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location) and the [actual documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure would be of great help. But aside from that.

Spring docs give an example of how to use the flag:

```
    --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties
```

Try resolving your application properties against the classpath.

Comment: I use the default structure (src/main/resouces/application.yml) but thats not the problem. I used the flag ok with the release versions of spring boot, but now the milestone version replaces the file. Just got a response from the team: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10971